# Limitar respuestas del json en python

Tags: python, json

Mi objetivo es el siguiente estoy utilizando una API para inventar nombres y demas datos, la API tiene muchos datos para yo solo traer uno como hago?

la API es la siguiente
[https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users]

Este es el codigo que uso

```
request = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    todos = json.loads(request.text)
    #show data
    for i in todos:
```

Comment: si les la documentacion te dira que puedes traer un resultado enviado en `id` si quieres el user 1 `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`

Comment: @Bryro asi es pero trato de que el resultado sea random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar el modulo random

ejemplo:

```
## el maximo de users para esa api es 10
import random
request = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
todos = json.loads(request.text)
#show data
# len() nos da la longitud en este caso 10
# randrange recibe un valor entero que ira de 0 a dicho valor
# en este caso 10
user_random = random.randrange(len(todos))
print(todos[user_random])
# tambien pudes usar el metodo choice
# que de un dict devuelve cualquier posicion
print(random.choice(todos))
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono